# Laravel foreach input all update fails because of form token

Tags: php, arrays, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I recently found my problem what is causing my form error.

I create a form post and loop throuh them

```
public function update()
    {

        $input = Input::all();

        foreach ($input as $key => $value) {

            $update = Setting::find($key);
            $update->value = $value;
            $update->save();
        }

        return Redirect::back();
    }
```

The problem is i get the following error

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

Because the token is included in the form post what Laravel automaticly renders to a form

if i stop using Laravel form open and use the html form tag it all works fine.

Is there any way to bypass this with laravel form open or should i use the html form tag?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

change

```
 $input = Input::all();
```

to

```
 $input = Input::except('_token');
```

Comment: Is there a way in laravel like `all`, that retrieves all needed form data without `_token` and `_method` ?  Or I need to extend request?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `$update = Setting::find($key);` returns a valid object, because, that error should be triggered when `$update` is NULL or not defined and you are trying to use this in your code

```
$update->value = $value;
```

This warning `Creating default object from empty value` occurs when [E_STRICT](http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php) is on in the system, but this is not the real problem, instead, you are not getting the desired result, most probably `Setting::find($key)` is not getting the thing you asked for and creating a new `Setting` object instead, check your model and make sure you are passing the right value in `::find($key)`, key should be `primary` key.

**Update :**
Also remember, when your using

```
$input = Input::all();
foreach ($input as $key => $value) { ... }
```

In this case, `$key` will be the name of your `input/field` used in the form and it may contain hidden `_token` field but `_token` is probably not available in the database as a `field/column`. So, you may try to get everything except `_token`

```
$input = Input::except('_token'); // get everything without _token
```

to get everything without `_token` field (but not sure if this solves the problem or not).